# Spring is not able to locate css/ js files

Tags: java, spring

I have created a project in Spring using Maven, AJAX and JSON. I am using HTML files instead of JSP and I have a problem loading the related CSS, JS Files in those HTML files.

I have seen related questions on this and also read several blogs on this issues and none of them work. (mvc:resources being the main answer in all of these).

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>Paying Guest Management</display-name>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.payingguest" />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/resources/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

references to those files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/main.css">
```

My application's directory structure
[image: Folder structure]

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mentioned that you tried `<mvc:resources>`, but what specifically did you try?  Also, your directory structure is not at all clear.  Is your `webapp` folder in the `java` directory?  Can you clarify how it is not working?  Are you getting a 404 for your resources?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. You can now see the folder structure of the app.

Comment: Can you specify what error you are getting when trying to access the static files?  Is it a 404 error, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try below .

```
<link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Sorry, Not working. This is the URL that is being sent to the server: http://localhost:8080/payingGuest/%3C%=request.getContextPath()%%3E/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: I thought you are using JSP,but it seems your using HTML then,it should be like below. <link href="your_app_name/resources/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="your_app_name/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: your_app_name means your war file name,that is getting created.Give it a try i think it should work.

Comment: I've tried this earlier. Gave it a try afresh and no Luck Again. The URL: http://localhost:8080/payingGuest/payingGuest/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css

payingGuest being the app name.

Comment: i think the URL should be simply http://localhost:8080/payingGuest/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css, you have written your app name two times,is it typo??

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Had no internet access these days. Anyway, no it is not a typo. If I'm referencing the CSS files as href="your_app_name/resources/css/main.css" then I'm getting the app name twice, as I've mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This will provide you the Application Context path 
 host:  localhost or Ip address 
port:  8080 
application name :  myApplicattion 
for:   http://localhost:8080/myApplicattion

will work even if the page is relocated to other folder structure.

```html
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/main.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/main.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```